# Trouble fetching data from firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

So this is going to be a bit long, but i will try to produce my issue quite simply. The full code of my component is at the end btw.

I am learning to use firebase authentication and adding and retrival of data from the firebase Firestone in react. I have the authentication set up and this gives me a unique ID that I can use to fetch the content I have added in real-time. The function that listen and fetches the data in the code below is listenForMessages() that is inside my useEffect hook. This function fetches the data updates the state in the content hook which then displays the data in my render. The issue is that right now to fetch the data I have to insert the unique ID (jYAhV0xCtmOEJtOPXHirYXkQtju1) directly into doc() inside this listenForMessages(). This is not ideal as I cannot be hardcoding the unique ID. So I switched things a little bit and passed the unique id I got from my app.js as a prop into this component. Thanks to the below bit of code the unique ID is now passed into the below usestate hook, which should then give me the freedom to use id in doc() in this manner= doc(id).

```
const [ id, setId ] = useState(props);

    useEffect(
        () => {
            setId(props.uid);
        },
        [ props ]
    );
```

The issue is that it simply doesn't work :/

When i add id into doc() I am met with this messege- FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: a custom Object object

can anyone help? :/

```
const [ id, setId ] = useState(props);

    useEffect(
        () => {
            setId(props.uid);
        },
        [ props ]
    );

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import fire, { db } from '../Config/firebase';

export default function Home(props) {
    function logout() {
        fire.auth().signOut();
    }

    const [ name, setName ] = useState('');
    const [ email, setEmail ] = useState('');
    const [ Content, setContent ] = useState([]);

    const [ id, setId ] = useState(props);

    useEffect(
        () => {
            setId(props.uid);
        },
        [ props ]
    );

    const sendData = () => {
        db
            .collection('users')
            .doc(props.uid)
            .set({
                name,
                email,
                id
            })
            .then(function() {
                console.log('Document successfully written!');
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.error('Error writing document: ', error);
            });
    };


    const listenForMessages = () => {
        db.collection('users').doc('jYAhV0xCtmOEJtOPXHirYXkQtju1').onSnapshot(function(doc) {
            const allMessages = [];
            allMessages.push(doc.data());
            setContent(allMessages);
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        listenForMessages();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>I am home</h1>
            <button onClick={logout}>Log out</button>

            <h1>Enter information</h1>
            <form>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
            </form>
            <button onClick={sendData}>Send data</button>
            {Content.map((n) => (
                <p key={Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)}>
                    {n.name} {n.email}
                </p>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the contents of `props.uid` at runtime?

Comment: @DougStevenson not too sure about what you mean by runtime as I am a bit of a noob to firebase, but what is passed down as props is the unique id. And if I hardcode the unique id into doc() and the code runs, I can see that id has been updated by the props as well. Issue is I just cant place this id into doc() without meeting this error

Comment: Sounds like you're going to have to debug what that value actually is, because the error is complaining about it.

Comment: When I console.log id, I get- {uid: undefined}. I reckon this is the issue, but I don't know how to move forward from here mate. Got any thoughts? Oh and also thank you for all those firebase vids! They helped a bunch :)

Comment: You're going to have to debug it.  We can't see where that value is coming from.

Comment: Can you show how do you invoking `Home`? What argument do you use to invoke this?